# How to retrieve data from iphone 4s when connector/charger is broken

Tags: iphone, data-transfer, charging

My iphone 4s charger/connector broke.  My phone ran out of battery, is unchargeable and unbootable.  It also will not connect to any computer or other device.  I took it to the Genius bar and they said there was nothing they could do to restore the phone or retrieve the data.

The problem is that I have important photos on the phone which I need access to.  How can I get access to it?  Are there services for that?  Is there a way to read the hard drive similar to a hard drive enclosure?

Comment: Was ICloud backup turned on?

Comment: No. @Tyson, it was not turned on.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  If the Genius Bar told you there was nothing that could be done, then I would look for 3rd party glass repair (I know your problem as stated doesn't include broken glass) those are the people/companies that might be able to cobble together some working parts from junked phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take it to any of the various iPhone repair kiosks that appear throughout most malls.

I took an old iPhone there and had the charger replaced for $45.

Comment: Agreed. You can also, if you like, perform the fix yourself using parts and guides from ifixit.com - I've done this for a 4S before and it takes about ~30min total to replace the 30pin.

Comment: Gah.  Frickin' "Genius Bar" teenager made it sound like changing them out was a task for Prometheus.  Took it to some dude on a street corner and he was done in 15 minutes.

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!