# iPhone not turning on, not responding to hard reset, not responding to charger

Tags: iphone, data-recovery

About 2 days ago, my iPhone 6 decided to stop working.

I tried to see what the error was but it decided not to respond to a charger, it would not respond to a hard reset or even when I tried to connect to iTunes.

I took it into a repair store, and they said when they tried several different things, like replacing battery, LCD, and even screen, it would not turn on.

I am getting a bit worried as there were a lot of important things that I had on that phone that cannot be recovered as they are specific to that phone and cannot be accessed anywhere else.

Please let me know any tips and anything I can do to try and make it work again.

Comment: Also, be sure you’ve exhausted the usual sequence for resuscitating a flat iOS device: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355306/iphone-7-is-frozen-and-i-cant-turn-it-off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would get a quote and send the device in to a microsoldering capable repair shop. These are highly specialized and not the typical, fix broken screen type shops.

They can and will fix liquid damage / no power on situations as well as make the system healthy enough in a lab setting to get you your data back and not spend even more money fixing it to run permanently.

- https://www.microsolderingrepairs.com/blog/iphonedatarecovery

No power / data recovery are generally less than $250 for non-liquid damaged phones and maybe double that if there is liquid damage / corrosion to be remediated.

You’ll possibly pay more than [going to shops like you visited](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/187445/how-to-retrieve-data-from-iphone-4s-when-connector-charger-is-broken), but the more capable shops have much more expensive tools and skills and can recover data that’s far too gone for a place that specializes on the easy repairs. These sort of shops are generally less expensive than full [blown data recovery shops](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194926/my-iphone-6-plus-is-bent-and-not-powering-on-need-to-retrieve-data-not-backup-t), but you might get a couple quotes before sending it off - just be sure what diagnostic fee you owe and when you are charged if they do or don’t get your data back.

Answer (score -1):

I've had good luck storing the phone in a bag of rice for a few days.
I've also sped up the process by putting it in the oven on 150 degrees for a bit.  (Think leaving the phone on the dash of your car for a few hours.) I wouldn't go above 150 for fear of melting the solder joints though.

Comment: You take out the battery before doing any of this, correct? And probably then replace the liquid damaged battery when you’re done testing.

Comment: No I did it as is.  But mine was not terribly wet.  Like I said it's like leaving your phone out in the sun in your car on a hot day.  But also like I suggested don't go nuts.